# Can't decide between Paired t-test and Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test?

Tags: wilcoxon-signed-rank, nonparametric

I'm using data for pre-2020 January-April and the year 2020 January-April (raw data with one datapoint per day, except for the 'pre-2020' category which is the values for one day in 2017, 2018, and 2019 all averaged to produce one datapoint for that day.

Since the measurements are taken at two different time points, the groups are related. The difference between the paried values is normally distributed, and the dependent variable (pollution levels) is continuous. Therefore I considered Paired-t test to be appropriate. HOWEVER, using a box and whisker plot, I found that both categories (pre-2020 and 2020) have outliers:

pre-2020 has 1 outlier in January, 2 in March, and 1 in April.

2020 has 1 outlier in March, and 1 in February.

Due to the presence of these outliers, I decided to do a Wilcoxon Signed-Rank Test, the non-parametric equivalent. But one of the requirements is for the two samples to be NOT normally distributed. I found that pre-2020 is normally distributed  and 2020 is only NOT normally distributed in February, all other months are normally distributed.

Therefore, I don't know which one to use! Neither of the full requirements can be met.

Comment: Do you have a priori reasons for considering these data points as outliers ? If not, maybe just consider these data as some extreme type of noise and use them for parametric test.

Comment: no, just from seeing a box and whisker plot label them as outliers. If I used the parametric test anyway, would I need to delete that data, or just use it anyway?

Comment: IMO, one can't, or should'nt, exclude data based only on the observation of such data. However if you feel this is outlier, which means you think such data point does not follow the law, the rules of the other, then you should Investigate this particular data point, to see what is broken, different about that data point.

Comment: If you find nothing special after investigation, you'd be best keeping it **IMO**